# Quite new to Swift : can't get my classes to interact

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
class Lion
{
    var name:String = "Default"
    var isAlive : Bool = false

    func eat(cow:Cow)
    {
        cow.isAlive = false
        print("Cow \(cow) was eaten by \(name)")
    }
}

var lion1 = Lion()
lion1.name = "Mufasa"
lion1.isAlive = true

var lion2 = Lion()
lion1.name = "Simba"
lion1.isAlive = true

var lion3 = Lion()
lion1.name = "Scar"
lion1.isAlive = true

class Cow
{
    var name:String = "Default"
    var isAlive : Bool = false

    func giveMilk ()
    {
        print("cow \(name) is now giving milk")
    }

    func die ()
    {
        print("Cow \(name) is now dead")
    }
}

var cow1 = Cow()
cow1.name = "Moo1"
cow1.isAlive = true

var cow2 = Cow()
cow2.name = "Moo2"
cow2.isAlive = true

var cow3 = Cow()
cow3.name = "Moo3"
cow3.isAlive = true

var cow4 = Cow()
cow4.name = "Moo4"
cow4.isAlive = true

var cow5 = Cow()
cow5.name = "Moo5"
cow5.isAlive = true

var cow6 = Cow()
cow6.name = "Moo6"
cow6.isAlive = true

var cow7 = Cow()
cow7.name = "Moo7"
cow7.isAlive = true

var cow8 = Cow()
cow8.name = "Moo8"
cow8.isAlive = true

var cow9 = Cow()
cow9.name = "Moo9"
cow9.isAlive = true

var cow10 = Cow()
cow10.name = "Moo10"
cow10.isAlive = true

class Cat
{
    var name:String = "Default"

    func eatMouse (mouse : Mouse)
    {
        print("Mouse \(mouse) was eaten")
    }

    func getMilk (cow:Cow)
    {
        if cow.isAlive == true
        {
            cow.giveMilk()
        }else{
            print("A dead cow cannot provide milk")
        }
    }
}

var cat1 = Cat()
cat1.name = "Meow1"

var cat2 = Cat()
cat2.name = "Meow2"

class Mouse
{
    var name:String = "Default"

    func die ()
    {
        print("Mouse \(name) is dead")
    }
}

var mouse1 = Mouse()
mouse1.name = "Micky"

var mouse2 = Mouse()
mouse2.name = "Mini"

var mouse3 = Mouse()
mouse3.name = "Rattata"

var mouse4 = Mouse()
mouse4.name = "Splinter"
```

When I run via Xcode , it tells me Cow, Mouse and Cat are "Use of undeclared type "class name" .

For the life of me, I can't figure it out ( Quite new so don't bash me). 
After establishing the classes I am supposed to have the system run several different scenarios where mouse is dead, cat eats mouse, lion eats cow etc'.

Comment: You need declare a class before you try to use it. Reorder things.

Comment: Also, why don't you have a base class `Animal` which has `name` and `isAlive` with the default value of `isAlive` set to `true`. It would save you a whole bunch of code.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Try to move class definitions ahead of others.

```
class Mouse
{
var name:String = "Default"

func die ()
{
    print("Mouse \(name) is dead")
   }
}

class Cow
{
var name:String = "Default"
var isAlive : Bool = false

func giveMilk ()
{
    print("cow \(name) is now giving milk")
}

func die ()
{
    print("Cow \(name) is now dead")
}
}

class Lion
{
var name:String = "Default"
var isAlive : Bool = false

func eat(cow:Cow)
{
    cow.isAlive = false
    print("Cow \(cow) was eaten by \(name)")
}
}

var lion1 = Lion()
lion1.name = "Mufasa"
lion1.isAlive = true

var lion2 = Lion()
lion1.name = "Simba"
lion1.isAlive = true

var lion3 = Lion()
lion1.name = "Scar"
lion1.isAlive = true



var cow1 = Cow()
cow1.name = "Moo1"
cow1.isAlive = true

var cow2 = Cow()
cow2.name = "Moo2"
cow2.isAlive = true

var cow3 = Cow()
cow3.name = "Moo3"
cow3.isAlive = true

var cow4 = Cow()
cow4.name = "Moo4"
cow4.isAlive = true

var cow5 = Cow()
cow5.name = "Moo5"
cow5.isAlive = true

var cow6 = Cow()
cow6.name = "Moo6"
cow6.isAlive = true

var cow7 = Cow()
cow7.name = "Moo7"
cow7.isAlive = true

var cow8 = Cow()
cow8.name = "Moo8"
cow8.isAlive = true

var cow9 = Cow()
cow9.name = "Moo9"
cow9.isAlive = true

var cow10 = Cow()
cow10.name = "Moo10"
cow10.isAlive = true

 class Cat
{
var name:String = "Default"

func eatMouse (mouse : Mouse)
{
    print("Mouse \(mouse) was eaten")
}

func getMilk (cow:Cow)
{
    if cow.isAlive == true
    {
        cow.giveMilk()
    }else{
        print("A dead cow cannot provide milk")
    }
   }
 }

 var cat1 = Cat()
 cat1.name = "Meow1"

  var cat2 = Cat()
 cat2.name = "Meow2"



 var mouse1 = Mouse()
 mouse1.name = "Micky"

 var mouse2 = Mouse()
 mouse2.name = "Mini"

 var mouse3 = Mouse()
 mouse3.name = "Rattata"

 var mouse4 = Mouse()
 mouse4.name = "Splinter"
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not nearly as useful as answers that clearly explain what was wrong and how the answer solves the issue. Please update your answer with some details.